# Read the each file name and check for the string using ant

Tags: ant

I have particular requirement. I have multiple reports file in particlar directly. Currently I build up ant script reading all files and checking for the particular string using the below code.

```
<target name="GenerateReports" >
<property name="search.string" value="Internal Error" />

<fileset id="existing" dir="${report.dir}">
<patternset id="files">
   <include name="*.txt" />
</patternset>
</fileset>

<fileset id="matches" dir="${report.dir}">
<patternset refid="files" />
<contains text="${search.string}" />
</fileset>


<fail message="Found '${search.string}' in one or more test cases results in '${report.dir}' One or more test cases are failed">
    <condition>
    <resourcecount when="greater" count="0" refid="matches" />
  </condition>
 </fail>


</target>
```

But i want to read each file and give the name of the file where the error exists in my report file.
How to read the each file name and read the content also.

Comment: It's possible to use a groovy script to do the job.  See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html for info on scripting.

Comment: Thanks ash for the reply. But i am strictly looking for ant taks to perform the job.

Comment: That's the link - an ant task that allows you to script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<foreach target="-List-File-Names" param="foreach.file" inheritall="true">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${report.dir}" includes="*.txt">
               <contains text="${search.string}" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
</foreach>


<target name="-List-File-Names">
    <dirname property="file.dir" file="${foreach.file}"/>
    <!-- dirname now holds the file -->

</target>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/27918226)